# Python - Extract hashtags from text; end at punctuation

Tags: python, twitter

For my programming class, I have to create a function according to the following description:

> The parameter is a tweet. This function should return a list containing all of the hashtags in the tweet, in the order they appear in the tweet. Each hashtag in the returned list should have the initial hash symbol removed, and hashtags should be unique. (If a tweet uses the same hashtag twice, it is included in the list only once. The order of the hashtags should match the order of the first occurrence of each tag in the tweet.)

I am unsure how to make it so the hashtag ends when punctuation is encountered (see second doctest example). My current code is not outputting anything:

```
def extract(start, tweet):
    """ (str, str) -> list of str

    Return a list of strings containing all words that start with a specified character.

    >>> extract('@', "Make America Great Again, vote @RealDonaldTrump")
    ['RealDonaldTrump']
    >>> extract('#', "Vote Hillary! #ImWithHer #TrumpsNotMyPresident")
    ['ImWithHer', 'TrumpsNotMyPresident']
    """

    words = tweet.split()
    return [word[1:] for word in words if word[0] == start]

def strip_punctuation(s):
    """ (str) -> str

    Return a string, stripped of its punctuation.

    >>> strip_punctuation("Trump's in the lead... damn!")
    'Trumps in the lead damn'
    """
    return ''.join(c for c in s if c not in '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~')

def extract_hashtags(tweet):
    """ (str) -> list of str

    Return a list of strings containing all unique hashtags in a tweet.
    Outputted in order of appearance.

    >>> extract_hashtags("I stand with Trump! #MakeAmericaGreatAgain #MAGA #TrumpTrain")
    ['MakeAmericaGreatAgain', 'MAGA', 'TrumpTrain']
    >>> extract_hashtags('NEVER TRUMP. I'm with HER. Does #this! work?')
    ['this']
    """

    hashtags = extract('#', tweet)

    no_duplicates = []

    for item in hashtags:
        if item not in no_duplicates and item.isalnum():
            no_duplicates.append(item)

    result = []
    for hash in no_duplicates:
        for char in hash:
            if char.isalnum() == False and char != '#':
                hash == hash[:char.index()]
                result.append()
    return result
```

I'm pretty lost at this point; any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Note: we are **not** allowed to use regular expressions or import any modules.

Comment: Well.. if you need to end on punctuation, and there aren't *that* many punctutation symbols, why not check if the next character is a punctuation mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do look a little bit lost.  The key to solving these types of problems is to divide the problem into smaller parts, solve those, and then combine the results. You've got every piece you need..:

```
def extract_hashtags(tweet):
    # strip the punctuation on the tags you've extracted (directly)
    hashtags = [strip_punctuation(tag) for tag in extract('#', tweet)]
    # hashtags is now a list of hash-tags without any punctuation, but possibly with duplicates

    result = []
    for tag in hashtags:
        if tag not in result:  # check that we haven't seen the tag already (we know it doesn't contain punctuation at this point)
            result.append(tag)
    return result
```

ps: this is a problem that is well suited for a regex solution, but if you want a fast `strip_punctuation` you could use:

```
def strip_punctuation(s):
    return s.translate(None, '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~')
```